# Is this the correct way to deal with a JavaScript promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise, serverless

Forgive me but I am new to JS promises. I think I need to use one for interacting with an AWS service, which writes to and pulls data from DynamoDB. I have a JavaScript app which is ran by the Serverless npm plugin, which defines exported functions as end points. In these endpoints after the promise has completed I need to bubble the data back up to the endpoint to expose it as a JSON body. See the code below.

```
exports.getBlog = async (event) => {
    return getBlogPost(event).then((data) => {
        console.log("worked", data);
        var response =  {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        };

        return response;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("didn't work");
        var response = {
            statusCode: 400,
            body: JSON.stringify(error.toString())
        };

        return response;
    });
}
```

What makes me think it's not right is that I have to create a `var response` and return it, and then return again outside of that in the root of `exports.getBlog`. Is this right? It makes the JSON print correctly, but am confused from reading tutorials online as to whether this is good practice?

If not, how would you return data from the promise and expose it as a JSON result?

In this example, `exports.getBlog` is referenced by the Serverless framework as an endpoint, like so:-

```
functions:
  get-blog:
    handler: api/blog.getBlog
    events:
      - http:
          path: api/v1/blog
          method: GET
          cors: true
```

Comment: If `getBlog()` is supposed to return a promise and if you want that promise to resolve (not reject) even when there's an error, then this will achieve that goal.  The `return response` sets the resolved value of the promise by returning a value from the `.then()` or `.catch()` handler.  The `return` in `return getBlogPost().then(...).catch(...)` returns the promise from the function.  You do need both to accomplish your goal and it is a perfectly fine practice.

Comment: Now, resolving the promise when there's an error (instead of rejecting the promise) is a bit more unconventional.  That depends upon what the caller is expecting and how the calling code is written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing the two. Here is with async/await

```
 exports.getBlog = async (event) => {
 try {
    var res = await getBlogPost(event);
    var data = res.data;
    console.log("worked", data);
    var response =  {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    };

    return response;
} catch(error) {
    console.log("didn't work");
    var response = {
        statusCode: 400,
        body: JSON.stringify(error.toString())
    };

    return response;
   }
}
```

and without

```
exports.getBlog = event => {
    return getBlogPost(event).then((data) => {
    console.log("worked", data);
    var response =  {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    };

    return response;
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log("didn't work");
    var response = {
        statusCode: 400,
        body: JSON.stringify(error.toString())
    };

    return response;
});
}
```

Good read: https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9

EDIT: adding [MDN's article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) on async/await and how one can rewrite promise code with it

Comment: Thanks for this. I feared I was mixing something or other. Will give this a go, thanks!

Comment: @MikeUpjohn sure. regarding 2 returns in 2nd example I believe you can remove the first one if you also remove the {} so it'd be exports.getBlog = event => getBlogPost(event).then ....

Comment: The `.catch` in the `async`/`await` snippet doesn't work

Comment: Much of the linked article is balderdash, especially the title.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 so I assume you wrote/know of a better one and can share with us ?

Comment: @IhorBodnarchuk, sorry that you should feel slighted by my comment but I really feel that the article is wrong to compare `async/await` with promises. It acknowledges (as it should) that "Async/await is actually just syntax sugar built on top of promises" but then persists in trying to persuede the reader that "Async/Await Blows Promises Away". 
As a primer, you can do worse than [this](https://javascript.info/async-await).
All through it's made clear that `Async/Await` is all about Promises; they are not competing concepts.

Comment: Thanks for the help here guys, I have gone with await fn().

Answer (score 1):

There are two main methods to write promise first using resolve and reject functions and second using .then and .catch function.

First case example:

```
let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => reject(new Error("Whoops!")), 1000);
});

// reject runs the second function in .then
promise.then(
  result => alert(result), // doesn't run
  error => alert(error) // shows "Error: Whoops!" after 1 second
);
```

Second case example:

If we’re interested only in successful completions, then we can provide only one function argument to .then:

```
let promise = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 1000);
});

promise.then(alert); // shows "done!" after 1 second
```

If we’re interested only in errors, then we can use null as the first argument: .then(null, errorHandlingFunction). Or we can use .catch(errorHandlingFunction), which is exactly the same:

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => reject(new Error("Whoops!")), 1000);
});

// .catch(f) is the same as promise.then(null, f)
promise.catch(alert); // shows "Error: Whoops!" after 1 second
```